# mdframed+tikz to display overfullrule

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

This may or may not be a bug, so I'll first ask it here before reporting.

In the following test case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\overfullrule=5pt

\def\sentence{%
  to be the morphism from $\delta^*$ to $(\delta')^*$ (resp.\ to
  $(\delta'')^*$) such that $h'((p', p'')a(q', q''))$}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true]
  \sentence
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[rightline=false,topline=false]
  \sentence
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

the overfullrule is drawn only in the first mdframed.  How can I make it work
in the second one too?  This silent ignoring of overfullrule can be really dangerous...

Thanks!

- TeXlive 2012.26892-2 on Arch Linux
- latest mdframed from GitHub (1.6c, mdframed.dtx 436 2012-06-23 09:49:13Z marco)

Comment: Without any lines the with of the text area is longer and so you will get an other output.

Comment: This is not the point; the two mdframed contain an overfull hbox, only the first one is signaled with an overfullrule. Thanks!

Comment: @Michaël The overfull rule *is* drawn: the message indeed ends with `q[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ))$ |` and the bar means precisely the rule. For some reason, with TikZ as frame method, this rule is not printed: everything that overflows the reserved area is blanked out (the two closing parentheses are missing too).

Comment: @egreg Yeah, I guessed that the rule was just clipped (all the more since I saw examples with only half the rule).  I prefered presenting the question without any guesswork :-)  Though I didn't know about the "|" meaning of the message; thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question lead to the new option `draft` which is now implement in the development branch.

https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed

---

The contents of the environment mdframed is saved in a savebox. The output, if you use `framemethod=tikz`, will be done by the environment `tikzpicture`. To allow the options of three different lines I must work with the command `\clip` provided by tikz which also clips the overfull boxes.

If you use the option `hidealllines=true` there is nothing to clip which results in the output of overfull boxes.

To show the overfull markers you can do the following:

```
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*\mdf@tikzbox@tfl[1]{%three or four borders
    %\clip
    \path(0,0)rectangle(\mdfboundingboxwidth,\mdfboundingboxheight);%
    \begin{scope}[mdfcorners]%
       \clip[preaction=mdfouterline]%
            [postaction=mdfbackground]%
            [postaction=mdfinnerline]#1;%
    \end{scope}%
    \path[mdfmiddleline,mdfcorners]#1;
  }%

\renewrobustcmd*\mdf@tikzbox@otl[2]{%one or two borders
    %\clip
    \path(0,0)rectangle(\mdfboundingboxwidth,\mdfboundingboxheight);%
    \begin{scope}
       \path[mdfouterline,mdfcorners]#1;%
       \clip[postaction=mdfbackground]#2;%
       \path[mdfinnerline,mdfcorners]#1;%
    \end{scope}%
    \path[mdfmiddleline,mdfcorners]#1;}%
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Probably an option for clipping or nonclipping should be used; maybe `draft`?

Comment: @egreg: Great idea.

Comment: Well, an answer from the man himself, great!  Removing those "clips" is what I did to make it work; I was expecting a cleaner answer: adding a draft option is indeed a great idea!  Thanks!

Comment: @Michaël: Added option

Comment: @Marco: Thanks a lot! Tested it, and found a little bug; see http://pastebin.com/LBS1K1N1 ; with a nil overfullrule, the text is on the left, and it is moved a little bit otherwise.

Comment: @Michaël: Use `draft=true`. The evaluation of `draft` as option fails if you use `draft` as package option. I don't know why ;-(

Comment: Ah right!  It works now.  I don't have a clue why it fixes the previous bug, but it does.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: In fact, it doesn't fix the bug I mentioned.  Can you try to compile http://pastebin.com/hHbWczta with draft=true and without it? The results differ, in that the draft=true version has the text shifted a little bit.  Thanks!